# Gatsby cloud CMS Previews are failing with: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: gatsby-cloud

I've been trying to get my Gatsby Cloud CMS Previews to work for like over a week now with no success. I've upgraded Gatsby to latest V3 (13.14.5) and all it's dependencies. When running `yarn upgrade-interactive` it says `success All of your dependencies are up to date.`.

My "normal" Gatsby Cloud builds runs without errors, but my CMS Preview fails with this:

```
ERROR Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8888

14:30:25 PM:
    at doListen (net.js:1516:7)

14:30:25 PM:
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)

14:30:25 PM:
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1379:12)
```

Any ideas? Is there anyway I can get in touch with the Gatsby team about this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found out that it had to do with my `webpack-bundle-anlyzer` trying to run in production. Removed usage from production and then it worked!